# A square as a rectangle with 4 sides of equal length in OWL 2

Tags: owl

In OWL 2, is it possible to define a class Square as a rectangle with 4 sides of the same length given the following classes?

```
Class: Rectangle
  SubClassOf: hasSide exactly 4 Side

Class: Side
  SubClassOf: hasLength exactly 1 Length
```

Thanks!

(Apologies if this question or a similar one has already been answered)

Comment: No, OWL doesn't have variables. You need SWRL rules to solve this.